# using an instance of appointment in the appointment model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model

I've created a form with some radio buttons and had to interpolate the `appointment.id` into the radio button and the label. However, Rails is throwing the error:

> undefined method `cancel_3` for Appointment.

So I have tried to make a method in the `Appointment` model to solve this by using `define_method` (see below). However as this is in the model, I'm unable to use the instance of appointment here.

Is there any way I can make this work?

```
 define_method "cancel_#{appointment.id}" do
   # ...
 end
```

```
<%= f.radio_button "cancel_#{appointment.id}", :true %>
<%= f.label "cancel_#{appointment.id}_true", "Yes", class: "modal-options cancel" %>
```

```
<%= simple_form_for :appointment, url: delete_admin_appointment_path(appointment) do |f| %>
```

Comment: You're trying to call a model's method but you're in the view layer, you can call a route/page (a controller action in the end)

Comment: And in that action you can call your model's method

Comment: The feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Method names should not include their parameters. Why not define the method `cancel_id` that returns the `appointment.id` (assuming your model `has_one` or `belongs_to` an `:appointment`)?

Answer (score 0):

update your form with

```
<%= simple_form_for @appointment, url: delete_admin_appointment_path(@appointment) do |f| %>
```

and in your controller

```
def new
  @apointment = Apointment.new
end
```

and radio button with

```
<%= f.radio_button "cancel_#{@appointment.id}", :true %>
<%= f.label "cancel_#{@appointment.id}_true", "Yes", class: "modal-options cancel" %>
```